# C# Casting Performance Implications

Tags: c#

When using the 'as' keyword in C# to make a cast which fails, null gets returned. What's going on in the background? Is it simply suppressing an exception so I don't have to write handling code for a failure?

I'm interested in the performance characteristics of it compared to a typical cast wrapped in a try-catch.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's using the IL instruction [`isinst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst.aspx) to perform the cast instead of the [`castclass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.castclass.aspx) instruction that is used when casting. This is a special instruction which performs the cast if it is valid, else leaves `null` on the stack if it isn't. So no, it doesn't just suppress an exception, and is orders of magnitude faster than doing so.

Note that there are some differences in behaviour between the `isinst` instruction and `castclass` - the main one being that `isinst` does not take into account user-defined cast operators, it only considers direct inheritance hierarchy, e.g. if you define the following two classes with no inheritance hierarchy but an explicit cast operator:

```
class A
{
    public int Foo;
}

class B
{
    public int Foo;

    public static explicit operator B(A a)
    {
        return new B { Foo = a.Foo };
    }
}
```

Then the following will succeed:

```
var a = new A { Foo = 3 };
var b = (B)a;
Console.WriteLine(b.Foo); // prints 3
```

However the following does not compile, with the error 'Cannot convert type 'A' to 'B' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion'

```
var a = new A { Foo = 3 };
var b = a as B;
```

So if you do have any user-defined casts set up (which are typically a bad idea on reference types, for this reason and others) then you should be aware of this difference.

Comment: What's the reason why it won't compile? I thought the 'as' is only evaluated upon code execution? Does that means the compiler also checks casting during compile-time?

Comment: @faulty - The compiler will statically verify casts where possible to make sure you aren't writing code that can't possibly succeed (I can't remember whether this was a warning or an error as I always have warnings as errors turned on).

Answer (score 9):

And to add to Greg's excellent post...

The first time a new Type is referenced at runtime, the CLR loads into memory a structure called `COREINFO_CLASS_STRUCT` ( or something similar) that contains, among other things, a pointer to the `COREINFO_CLASS_STRUCT` object for the base class that this object derives from... This effectively creates a linked list of `COREINFO_CLASS_STRUCT` objects for the inheritance chain for the Type, which terminates in the `COREINFO_CLASS_STRUCT` for `System.Object`.   When you execute `isinst`, (or it's analogous method `castclass`)  it simply has to find the `COREINFO_CLASS_STRUCT` memory structure for the concrete type of the object you are examining, and traverse this linked list to see if the Type you are trying to cast to is in the list.

It also contains a pointer to a separate array which contains all the interfaces implemented by the Type, which must be searched separately if you are trying to cast to an interface.